# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context というエラー (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode

async/awaitを使ったGETリクエストのコードを書いてます。
7行目の`await`に`Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`
というエラーをもらいます。曖昧な表現です〜というエラーであることはわかったのですが、どこをどう表現すればいいのかわかりません。解決策お願いします。

```
import Foundation

func request(with url: String) async throws -> String {
    do {
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) //該当

        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            print("invalid response")
        }

        if response.statusCode == 200 {
            print(data)
        } else {
            print("serverErrorStatusCode:\(response.statusCode)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("clientSideError:\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
```

とするとどうなりますか？

Comment: `url` の部分に```Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URL' ```というエラーが出ました。3行目```func request(with url: String)```の部分を```func request(with url: URL)```にしたらエラーが消えました！ありがとうございます！